# Font Size changes according to count of word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function test(data) {
  wordCount = {};
  theWords = [];
  allWords = data.match(/\b\w+\b/g); //get all words in the document

  for (var i = 0; i < allWords.length; i = i + 1) {
    allWords[i] = allWords[i].toLowerCase();
    var word = allWords[i];
    if (word.length > 5) {
      if (wordCount[word]) {
        wordCount[word] = wordCount[word] + 1;
      } else {
        wordCount[word] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  var theWords = Object.keys(wordCount); // all words over 5 characters
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < theWords.length; i = i + 1) {
    result = result + " " + theWords[i];
    $("theWords.eq[i]").css("fontSize", (wordCount.length + 50) + 'px');

  }
  return result;
}

console.log(test("MyWords"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm having troubles with the syntax of the line  "$("theWords[i]......."

I realize how simple of a question this is, and not academic to the community, but I have been fumbling with this syntax for awhile and can't find any specific forum to correct my syntax error.

I am attempting to have the font size change according to the amount of times the word appears in a document.
 wordCount = count of appears.
 theWords = all words I would like to have the rule applied to

Comment: Are `$("theWords[i]")` elements within document ? Can you include `html` at Question ?

Comment: correct, the program as of right now will correctly count each word according to web inspector

Comment: Is `"theWords"` a `className` of elements ? Try `$(".theWords").eq(i)`

Comment: 'theWords' are all words in the document that contain over 5 chars. I would like to have the line I specified be a function to implement font size based on wordCount.length. I am in beginning steps of learning HTML, sorry for my poor vocabulary and knowledge.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: I added more of the index.html page. It is referencing two text documents.  I just cannot figure out the syntax of applying the css style font size to adapt according to wordCount.length

Comment: Can you include actual `html` of `document` at Question ?

Comment: https://github.com/tejaswigowda/ame220Spring2016/tree/master/wordCloud/public  contains the 5 components of the program, sorry for my lack of familiarity here on Stack. Thank you for your patience and help

Answer (score 0):

I manage to have something working with what you did using a bit more of jQuery to build the list of words to show. hope it helps :D.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
var data = $(".sometext").text();

wordCount = {}; theWords = []; allWords = data.match(/\b\w+\b/g);   //get all words in the document

for (var i = 0; i < allWords.length; i++){
  allWords[i] = allWords[i].toLowerCase();
  var word = allWords[i];
  if (word.length > 5) {
    if (wordCount[word]) {
      wordCount[word] = wordCount[word] + 1;
    } else {
      wordCount[word] = 1;
    }
  }
}

var theWords = Object.keys(wordCount); // all words over 5 characters
  
for(var i = 0; i < theWords.length; i = i + 1) {
  $('<span/>', {
    'text': theWords[i] + " ",
    'class': theWords[i]
  }).appendTo('.result');
}
  
for(var i = 0; i < theWords.length; i++) {
  $("." + theWords[i]).css("font-size", 15 + wordCount[theWords[i]]*5 + "px");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="sometext">javascript is a language that could be a language without such things as language but not without things as parenthesis. language is the bigest word here.</p>

<hr>

<div class="result"></div>
```